# Regex Match Roman Numerals from 0-39 Only

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that will match Roman numerals from 0 to 39 only. There are plenty of examples which match much larger Roman numerals, but I cannot figure out how to match this specific subset.

Comment: What new character does 40 add?

Comment: Might be easier to match all Roman numerals and have other parts of your code parse out the 0 to 39. Of course, that's if you have this option available.

Comment: 40 adds the new character L.

Comment: @timolawl I don't have that option available :/

Comment: Since all numerals less than 40 only use the characters I, V and X, and all numerals greater than or equal to 40 have at least one additional character, you should be able to write a regex matching numerals with only I, V and X.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Try this:

```
/^(X{1,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$|^(I[XV]|V?I{1,3})$|^V$/
```

#### Update:

Zero [doesn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero) in Roman numerals. Therefore feel free to tack on your own implementation for zero.

Comment: In general I think it's not good to duplicate matching (for example, XI can match the first or second alternative). You can update the second part to not start with X.

Comment: @justhalf Good catch.

Comment: You should put `anchor` or word boundary otherwise it is accepting `IIIII`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to represent 0 using Roman numerals. I assume that it has separate token `N` (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero)).

Assuming the regex tries to match the whole string (like in Java) and you have [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can use this regex:

```
(?.)(X{0,3}(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})|N)
```

Explanation:

- `(?.)`: ensure at least one character
- `X{0,3}`: define the tens (0, 10, 20, 30)
- `(...)`: define the final digit
- `IX`: 9
- `IV`: 4
- `V?I{0,3}`: 0-3, 5-8 (0 not as whole number, require at least one `X`)
- `N`: 0 (as whole number)

If you represent 0 as empty string, the regex is simpler:

```
X{0,3}(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})
```

since the lookahead and `N` in the previous regex is just to prevent empty string.

Comment: It matches X, and I already said that I assume it tries to match the whole string =) (oops, yes, the first one doesn't)

Comment: the 0 in `X{0,3}` is unnecessary

Comment: @rock321987: Yes, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know you have valid Roman numerals and want to fetch only the ones <= 39, that is easy:

```
^[XVI]*$
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/dgFucLQGe0)

---

If that is not the case, it's a little bit trickier, but you can still take advantage of the fact that all the numbers that can be represented only with `X`, `V` and `I` are 1..39:

```
^X{0,3}(?:V?I{0,3}|I[VX])$
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/aMkakar2JD)

- `X{0,3}` covers 10, 20, 30
- `X{0,3}V?I{0,3}` covers all but the ones that end with 4 or 9 (14, 29, etc)
- `X{0,3}I[VX]` exactly the ones ending with 4 or 9

**Note**: these will also match an empty string, which is my interpretation of a Roman zero. If that is not the case, you can replace the `*` with `+` for the first regex and add a positive lookahead at the start of the regex for the second (`(?=.)`).

**Note 2**: If they are not on separate lines (or in separate strings), you can replace `^` and `$` with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`).